# Android Studio Doesn't Recognize Gradle Version

Tags: android, gradle

I've been working on a project in AS for a while, but now it suddenly says 
"Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6. Current version is 4.4." and that I should edit gradle-wrapper.properties. I have seen a lot of posts on here with this problem. However, I have already been using Gradle 4.6 and plugin 3.2.0-alpha13 for a month. Has anyone heard of this before?
If you are curious, a similar, but not same, error is here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9dtlb8/android_studio_prints_an_error_requiring_to/
Thanks for reading!

Comment: AS v3.2 needs to upgrade the gradle version to at least 4.6.

Comment: That's what I'm saying--I have 4.6 specified in the wrapper distributionUrl. Nowhere in the code do I have a 4.4, so I don't understand why it is saying that I need to update. And thanks for the fast reply:).

Answer (score 0):

You can try update Android Studio to `3.2.1` and update android plugin to `3.2.1` and then update gradle-wrapper to `4.6`. If you use Kotlin try to set kotlin version 1.2.71. This should help.

Comment: That didn't work, but thanks for the idea. I just found out that that code was very poorly written and I will hopefully never touch it again!